# Critique my proof of: For every integer $x$, the remainder when $x^2$ is divided by $4$ is either $0$ or $1$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Critique my proof on structure, correctness, etc.

*Proof.* Let x be any arbitrary integer.

**Case #1**

Suppose $x$ is even. Thus, $x = 2k$ and $x^2 = 4k^2$. The quotient of $x^2$ and $4$ is $k^2$, so the remainder is zero.

**Case #2**

Suppose $x$ is odd. Thus, $x = 2k + 1$ and $x^2 = 4(k^2 + k) + 1$. The quotient of $x^2$ and $4$ is $k^2 + k$ with a remainder of one.

After exhausting all cases, it is evident that for every integer $x$, the remainder when $x^2$ is divided by $4$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You should say : If $ x $ is even, then there exists an integer $ k $ such that $ x=2k....$

Comment: You should use modular arithmetic instead.

Comment: I begin to like your Critique series.

Comment: Note the description of the solution-verification tag: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. **This should not be the only tag for a question.**" (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @prets I think I had another tag, but it was dropped for some reason and I didn't bother to go back and add a replacement. I'll be more mindful of that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is completely correct. One way to unify the two cases and thereby make it marginally "slicker" is to use the Division algorithm (which is also a way to guarantee that your two cases covers every eventuality).

For example: by the Division algorithm, we can write $x = 2 k + r$ for some (unique) integers $k$ and $r$ with $r = 0$ or $r = 1$.
In either case,
$$
x^2 = (2 k + r)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k r + r^2 = 4(k^2 + k r) + r^2,
$$
and so the remainder of $x^2$ when divided by $4$ is $r^2 = 0$ or $1$, since $r = 0$ or $1$.

Though there is of course no meaningful difference between this and your proof, other than writing both cases in one go.